# How do i set width of img to body width in container if it has max width?

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, corporis!</p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080,jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

So if i want img to be 100% width of body, how do i do it? I tried using calc(-50vw + 50%) and max width to 100vw but it makes horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Make the image's width 100% like so:

```css
img#placeholder {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Make sure you give the id #placeholder to the image**.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

img#placeholder {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, corporis!</p>
  <img id = 'placeholder' src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080,jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: That doesen't do what I want. What i want is for img inside container class to get out of container width of 1170px, to spread full width of a body.

Answer (score -1):

If the container is the first element in body then this will work

It is important to use `box-sizing: border-box;` to avoid a horizontal scrollbar because you're using a padding on the container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, corporis!</p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080,jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: **down-voted for following reason**: Answer misses simplicity. The approach to solve this is far to complicated for such a simple issue. Nearly none of what you descripe is actually necessary.